# Dynamically Clear and Update d3.js Force Directed Layout On Change

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With [the Mobile Patent Suit example by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) as an example, I was able to re-create using my own data, but I want to take it a step further and dynamically update the node relationships on a drop-down change. The code works almost every time, but occasionally I get a single node with no relationships (see image below) even though data are available. I think I may be doing something wrong when clearing and then updating the nodes on a selection change, but it's strange to me that is works some of the time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/calanoue/r6BRr/

```
var selectedCode = '0';

function updateNodes() {
   // Update the links and the nodes any time the data changes
   svg.selectAll('g').remove();

   links = allData[0][selectedCode];

   // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
   links.forEach(function (link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
   });

   force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(80)
        .charge(-400)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

   path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link relationship")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#relationship)");

   circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr('class', "generic")
        .attr("r", 8)
        .call(force.drag);
}

function tick() {
   // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
   path.attr("d", linkArc);
   circle.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
   var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
   return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
   return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

function clearNodes() {
   nodes = {};
   links = [];
   force.start();
   d3.timer(force.resume);
}

function codeChange() {
   selectedCode = this.value;
   clearNodes();
   updateNodes();
}
```

Missing Node Relationship Image:

[image: missing node relationships]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you were having is that your original data, `allData`, was being changed by the computation of links and nodes at each data change iteration. After all, you set `links = cloneData[0][selectedCode];`. You need to clone `allData` before each data change.

```
function codeChange() {
    selectedCode = this.value;
    cloneData = clone(allData); // added
    clearNodes();
    updateNodes();
}
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6ehtn/) with all the changes to make it work. I borrowed the clone function from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).

NOTE: I also removed one of your dropdown choices since you only have 3 sets of data in `allData`. That was not the cause of your problems, per above, but it was throwing errors whenever you selected the inexistent set.